# A parametrization of subsets

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

Suppose $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$, and let $\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus I=\{j_1,\dots,j_m\}$ be an enumeration of the complement of $I$ with $j_r<j_{r+1}$ for each $r\in\{1,\dots,m-1\}$. To $I$ I can attach the sequence $p(I)=(p_1,\dots,p_m)$ of non-negative integers with $p_r=|\{i\in I:i<j_r\}|$, which is such that $0\leq p_1\leq\cdots\leq p_m\leq n-m$. Conversely. each such sequence arises from exactly one $I$.

This bijection arises in a homological computation I am trying to do. I have something parametrized in terms of the $I$'s and I want to single out those that satify a condition best expressed in terms of the $p(I)$'s, and this is turning to be somewhat incovenient... It would probably be useful to me to know:

> Has this bijection showed up in some other context?

Comment: I didn't realize that was the collective word for subsets, as a pride of lions, a murder of crows, or an exaltation of larks.

Comment: For "...$\setminus U$..." did you mean "...$\setminus I$..."?

Comment: There is a well-known correspondence between compositions of $n$ and subsets of $[n-1]$ that is important (at least for notation) in the theory of quasisymmetric functions: see the third paragraph of section 7.19 of Stanley's EC2. But your bijection is slightly different than this.

Answer (score 2):

In computability theory, the function $r\mapsto j_r$ is called the *principal function* of the set $J=\{j_1<\dots<j_m\}$ and denoted $p_J$. The relation with your function being that $p_r=j_r-r$, i.e., you're just subtracting the identity function from the principal function of the complement of $I$.